# Change css with jquery without any transition appearing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two buttons and want them to be next to each other. I had to use jquery to achieve this, because as soon as i clicked the "Forward" button, then the "Previous" button appeared and the Forward button moved to the bottom, even though i use "display:inline-block".

It works fine, but there is one problem. As soon as the css is changed by jQuery, it is possible to see how the buttons "transit" to their new positions, as you can see in my [jsfiddle code](https://jsfiddle.net/69802n3f/).

**Question:** Is there a way to change this behaviour and let the change be visible without any transition or delay?

```
<div id="mydiv_buttons">
    <div style="padding:20px;">
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <table style="margin-left: 500px">
                <tr>
                    <td><a class="btn"      id="btn_arrow-prev" >       <p class="button_text"> Previous    <i class="fa fa-angle-double-left"></i></p></a></td>
                    <td><a class="btn"      id="btn_arrow-next" >       <p class="button_text"> Forward     <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i></p></a></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.btn {
    -moz-user-select: none;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1.42857;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.btn {
    background-image: none !important;
    border: 5px solid #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 0;
    box-shadow: none !important;
    color: #FFFFFF !important;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) !important;
    transition: all 0.15s ease 0s;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.btn, .btn-default, .btn:focus, .btn-default:focus {
    background-color: #ABBAC3 !important;
    border-color: #ABBAC3;
}

.button_text
{
    margin-top: 7px;
    font-size: 15px;
}

#mydiv_buttons
{
    margin-top: 440px;
    width:100%;
    height:20%;

    border-top: 1px solid #D8D8D8;
}
```

jQuery:

```
var main = function()
{
    var counter = 1;
    var m_left = "148px";

    if (counter === 1)
    {
        $("#btn_arrow-next")            .css("display", "inline-block");
        $("#btn_arrow-next")            .css("margin-left", m_left);        

        $("#btn_arrow-prev")            .css("display", "none");        
        $("#btn_fertig_stellen")        .css("display", "none");        
    } 

    $('#btn_arrow-next').click
    (
        function()
        {
            counter = counter + 1;

            if (counter === 1)
            {
                $("#btn_arrow-next")            .css("display", "inline-block");    
                $("#btn_arrow-next")            .css("margin-left", m_left);    

                $("#btn_arrow-prev")            .css("display", "none");
                $("#btn_fertig_stellen")        .css("display", "none");
            } 
            else if (counter === 2)
            {
                $("#btn_arrow-next")            .css("display", "inline-block");
                $("#btn_arrow-next")            .css("margin-left","0px");
                $("#btn_arrow-prev")            .css("display", "inline-block");
            }

        }
    );

    $('#btn_arrow-prev').click
    (
        function()
        {
            counter = counter - 1;

            if (counter === 1)
            {
                $("#btn_arrow-next")            .css("display", "inline-block");
                $("#btn_arrow-next")            .css("margin-left", m_left);

                $("#btn_arrow-prev")            .css("display", "none");
                $("#btn_fertig_stellen")        .css("display", "none");
            } 
            else if (counter === 2)
            {
                $("#btn_arrow-next")            .css("display", "inline-block");
                $("#btn_arrow-next")            .css("margin-left","0px");
                $("#btn_arrow-prev")            .css("display", "inline-block");
            }

        }   
    );

}

$(document).ready(main);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/69802n3f/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `transition` was set in the CSS, remove `transition: all 0.15s ease 0s;` from the `btn` class.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69802n3f/2/)

Comment: Thank you very much. This is what happens when you just copy & paste without checking the code and learning what it does... lesson learned, thx!

Answer (score 1):

transition appearing because of css.

Remove below css

```
.btn {transition: all 0.15s ease 0s;}
```

Demo :https://jsfiddle.net/69802n3f/3/